# Using $u_1=(1,1,1,1),u_2=(0,1,1,1),u_3=(0,0,1,1),u_4=(0,0,0,1)$ create an arbitrary vector $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4$ as a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am not really sure how to do this question, I think it has something to do with setting up a matrix for Gaussian reduction so that you can find what $q,r,s,t$ need to be so that the following is true:

$$ (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = q\vec{u_1} + r\vec{u_2} + s\vec{u_3} + t\vec{u_4} $$

Is there something to do with span as well?

Comment: Write the $u_i$ as the rows of a matrix $A$.  Can you set up a matrix equation equivalent to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The condition you wrote is basically
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
q\\
r\\
s\\
t
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
a_4
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Which is just a matrix equation that you can solve using Gaussian elimination (or any other method if you like).

In this particular example, I think it might be easier to just construct the Cartesian basis vectors from the $u$'s first.

Span of a set of vectors just means all the possibilities that arise from linearly combining those vectors, so here you just need to double check that the given four $u$'s are indeed capable of recreating all possible 4d vectors when linearly combined (ie. that their span is $\mathbb{R}^4$). If you're able to solve the aforementioned matrix equation without problems, that should mean that you have nothing to worry about, the span is what it should be.

Comment: So i have reduced it by elimination, and I have a matrix in the identity form, and i have then the appended matrix like $(a_1, a_2 - a_1, a_3 - a_2, a_4 - a_3)$ if we replace $q,r,s,t$ with $a_1$ through to $a_4$ because I am a fool and it is easier that way. Then I know that $a_1 u_1 + (a_2 - a_1)u_2 \cdots$ and so on, but what to from there? @Raad Shaikh

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit confused, ignore the replacing comment.

Comment: That's it, you're done. You were given $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 $ and you wanted to find $q, r, s, t $ that satisfy the equation. You've determined that $q=a_1, r=a_2-a_1, $ etc.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much.